# Probability of two events with $P = 1 - O (n^{-c})$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Suppose we have two independent events, each with probability $P = 1 - O (n^{-c})$.  What can we say about the probability that both events happen?

I think it's $P = 1 - O (n^{-2c})$, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the big O calculus correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A^c$ denote the complement of event $A$.

By a [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality),
$$P(A \cap B) = 1 - P(A^c \cup B^c) \ge 1 - P(A^c) - P(B^c).$$

so if $P(A^c) \le C n^{-c}$ and $P(B^c) \le C n^{-c}$, then $1-P(A \cap B) \le C' n^{-c}$.